# UITapGestureRecognizer on a subview of MKAnnotationView not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkannotationview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am trying to add tap recognizer to show additional information callout. I tried calling the selector "showPersonInfo" directly and it's working. But, when I try to add it in a UITapGestureRecognizer on a subview of the MKAnnotationView I am working on. The selector is not firing when I tap.

This code is inside .m of a subclass of MKAnnotationView

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {

    [self addSubView:self.imageContainerView];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showPersonInfo:)];
    [self.imageContainerView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

}

- (void)showPersonInfo:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap {

    NSLog(@"annotation imageView touched");
    [self addSubview:self.personInfoView];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mapView Delegate method for adding actions to your annotation view

```
 - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
    {
        if (annotation == mapView.userLocation)
            return nil;

        static NSString *s = @"identifier";
        MKAnnotationView *pin = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:s];
        if (!pin) {
            pin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:s];
            pin.canShowCallout = YES;
            pin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin.png"];
            pin.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
            UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
            [button addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(showPersonInfo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            pin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button;
        }
        return pin;
    }
```

Comment: I have added a tittle to the annotation but, even - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view still would not fire.

Comment: its getting called for me.check for MKMapViewDelegate is set properly or not.

Comment: I know now what the problem was. I did not set the MKAnnotationView's image which serve at least in my case as hit area. Then used the button you provided above to execute the selector. Thanks @Suhail k. Now the callout is showing.

Comment: Cool.Am not getting what s the exact problem was?

Answer (score 1):

The two things you need to aware of :

**By default the `UIIMageView.userInteraction` is `disabled`**

```
   self.imageContainerView.userinteractionenabled = yes;
```

**UITapGesture:**

```
[tapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[tapRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
```

Comment: self.imageContainerView is just UIView with multiple UIImageView inside. will that affect the recognizer?

Comment: No, Check the UITapGesture properly